# Delete a value from cookie with php

Tags: php, cookies

I am storing product id-s in a cookie with php. (These are the favorite products on a webshop.)

I added many products as favorit, so my cookie looks like: 12,55,120,43

What i know, that the `$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]` is not an array. (checked with `is_array` function)

How can i delete a product id from that cookie? I send the id that i want to delete with ajax to this php file:

```
    if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $id = intval($_POST['id']);

    $cookie_name = "kedvenc_termek";
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
    {
        echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    }

}
```

Comment: It's possible that you've got a different index name for your cookie (for example, there might be a typo in the code that sets the cookie). Try to see what indexes and values your `$_COOKIE` has. You can use something like `print var_dump($_COOKIE);` to see the indexes and values that exist.

Comment: `unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);` ???

Answer (score 0):

This should delete or invalidate cookie

```
// set the expiration date to one hour ago

setcookie($cookie_name, " ", time() - 3600);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unset your cookie:

```
unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
```

Set your cookie null:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, null, -1, '/');
```

Comment: No, because that will delete all of the content from itt. I just want to delete a number from it.

Comment: @max777 I believe my answer does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you have a string stored in the cookie like `12,55,120,43` and you want to remove one of them using `$_POST['id']`?
Since it's a string I believe the best option is preg_replace() this gives you the benefit over str_replace that you can create a pattern to remove.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$cookie_name = "kedvenc_termek";
$_COOKIE[$cookie_name] = preg_replace("/\b(" . preg_quote($id) . ",)\b/", "", $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
```

If you want to store the new string in the cookie then be sure to do that before you echo the value since you can't set a cookie after an output.

Example: https://3v4l.org/RQH4o